# Intention "Sort Content" not availlable on some enum files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, enums

IntelliJ has an Intention to sort the members of an enum alphabetically, we use this to avoid merge conflicts when adding new members to the enum.

This works for the majority of our enum files, but doesn't seem availlable for a couple of enums.

I know the intention doesn't show up when the members are already sorted, but this isn't the case.

Is there another condition for this intention to show up ?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1

Comment: Can you please share the enum sample? Thanks

Comment: I can't share the original enum, because of company policy and I can't reproduce it with a custom enum :( I did notice that when the name of EVERY member of the enum changes (bij adding a temporary suffix) the "Sort Content" intention becomes availlable. I don't know why this is, but it is an workaround that solves my current problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the suffix you add the same for all the enum values? You may create an issue at the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ and make it private (or make the attached info private) so that only JetBrains developers can see it.